# Multiplication of data when filling text boxes using pandas, tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to fill text boxes with data get from excel file using pandas, but the data is getting multiplied (in de df, not on GUI) after I do that

here is the part of the code that causes the problem

```
# Extract number of rows and columns
    n_rows = df.shape[0]
    n_cols = df.shape[1]
    
    # Initialize current_row with the total number of rows in the dataframe
    current_row = n_rows

    # Extracting columns from the data and creating text widget with some background color
    column_names = df.columns
    i=0
    n_rows = df.shape[0]
    for j, col in enumerate(column_names):
        text = Text(window, width=20, height=1, font=('Arial', 10,'bold'), bg = "#9BC2E6")
        text.grid(row=i,column=j, sticky="ew")
        text.tag_configure("tag_name", justify='center')
        text.insert(INSERT, col)
        text.tag_add("tag_name", "1.0", "end")
        
    # adding all the other rows into the grid
    for i in range(n_rows):
        for j in range(n_cols):
            cell_text = Text(window, width=len(str(df.loc[i][j])), height=1, font=('Times', 8))
            cell_text.grid(row=i+1,column=j, sticky="ew")
            cell_text.tag_configure("tag_name", justify='center')
            cell_text.insert(INSERT, df.loc[i][j])
            cell_text.tag_add("tag_name", "1.0", "end")
            cells[(i,j)] = cell_text

            # create button widget and add it to the grid
            cell_button = Button(window, text="Copy Row", command=lambda row=i: copy_row(cells, n_cols, row))
            cell_button.grid(row=i+1,column=n_cols)
```

I tried so many things that I lost track... I expected it to fill the text boxes and keep the df as it was imported...

it gets imported as:

```
N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
```

after it gets writen to the text box widgets, the df looks like this:

```
 N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
  N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
  N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
  N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
  N° do item                                                                 descricao do item quant     lot         fab         val
0     P05542  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 37 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     3  123123  2005/05/02  2006/02/02
1     P05544  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 39 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     2     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
2     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5     123  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
3     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1234  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
4     P05545  BOTINA HORIZON DACAR C CADARCO EM VAQUETA 40 MARROM LHR 40123257 CA 40872 BRACOL     5    1235  2005/02/02  2006/02/02
```

And I don't understand why...
I'm new to coding and also to stackoverflow, so forgive any mistake I've made.

Comment: At a guess, you probably don't need the nested `for` loop. It looks to me like the data is read as desired after the first loop iteration

Comment: you mean the #adding all the other rows into the grid?